# Wine: ntdll.dll caused Access Violation running Unity Server

Tags: linux, wine, unity3d

Recently I moved over to a new RootServer and I wanted to install an Valheim Server on there. Because the Server is windows only I use wine to run it.
On the old server this works perfectly fine but now nothing seems to work anymore.
Old Server was a VPS had 16G Ram and 8 Cores CPU Intel Xeon if I remember correctly. The new Server is a RootServer also with 16G Ram and an AMD EPYC-Rome Processor with 6 Cores.

When starting the server with the following command, it crashes instantly:

```
xvfb-run wine valheim_server.exe -nographics -batchmode <args>
```

The provided Crash Report says the following:

```
ntdll.dll caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module ntdll.dll at 0033:7bc9ab24.

Error occurred at 2022-03-17_142204.
Z:\home\valheim\valheim_server.exe, run by root.

9% physical memory in use.
18059 MB physical memory [16314 MB free].
55 MB process peak paging file [55 MB used].
93 MB process peak working set [74 MB used].
System Commit Total/Limit/Peak: 0MB/0MB/0MB
System Physical Total/Available: 18059MB/0MB
System Process Count: 7
System Thread Count: 25
System Handle Count: 448
Disk space data for 'C:\users\root\Temp\IronGate\Valheim\Crashes\Crash_2022-03-17_132156963\': 84346494976 bytes free of 105620869120 total.

Read from location 0000000C0006B7D8 caused an access violation.

Context:
RDI:    0x000000007bd18060  RSI: 0x000000007bd18060  RAX:   0x00000002fffffffd
RBX:    0x000000000006d030  RCX: 0x000000007bd180c0  RDX:   0x00000000000100b0
RIP:    0x000000007bc9ab24  RBP: 0x000000000021eb70  SegCs: 0x0000000000000033
EFlags: 0x0000000000010206  RSP: 0x000000000021ea80  SegSs: 0x000000000000002b
R8:     0x0000000000120000  R9:  0x0000000000080000  R10:   0x0000000000000002
R11:    0x000000000006d028  R12: 0x0000000000000000  R13:   0x000000000006b7e0
R14:    0x0000000060ae0000  R15: 0x0000000000000000


Bytes at CS:EIP:
41 8b 44 85 04 4c 89 6b 20 48 c7 43 30 00 00 00 

No mono DLL path set. This app is either running IL2CPP, or the crash occurred before mono was initialized.
```

After this wine also displays the following errors:

```
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0xc0006b7d8 at address 0x7bc9ab24 (thread 002c), starting debugger...
002e:err:seh:setup_exception stack overflow 1712 bytes in thread 002e eip 000000007bc9c2b9 esp 0000000000140f60 stack 0x140000-0x141000-0x240000
```

Because I never use wine I'm pretty clueless at this point.

My wine version is **4.0** at **Debian 4.0-2**.

Help is appreciated. If there is anything more I need to share feel free to tell me.

Greetings!

Comment: What are the differences between the new server and the old server? ]Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound Edited. The new Server runs 32 Bit and the Exe 64 Bit, can this result in the problem?

Comment: 32-bit operating systems do NOT support 64-bit applications.

Answer (score 0):

If it is true that you're running a 64bit application on a 32bit server, then that there is your problem.

While a 32bit application can run on a 64bit host, a 32bit host is incapable of running 64bit programs.